# SQL performance - Understanding to read the table

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have developed a report and it takes more than 1hr for execution hence i have enabled the trace and trying to understand below table.

Which one is causing an issue from the below picture. It looks like code_combinations table is causing the issue. please correct me if i am wrong. Please refer the screenshot to check the SQL plan. I am looking for suggestions to reduce the execution time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12J94.jpg)

```
SELECT gjs.user_je_source_name "JOURNAL_SOURCE",
gjc.user_je_category_name "JOURNAL_CATEGORY",
gl.currency_code,
0 AS reportingdebit,
0 AS reportingcredit,
Sum(Nvl(gl.accounted_dr, 0)) AS ledgerdebit,
Sum(Nvl(gl.accounted_cr, 0)) AS ledgercredit,
gl.code_combination_id,
gc.segment1,
gc.segment2,
gc.segment3,
gc.segment4,
gc.segment5,
gc.segment6,
gc.segment7,
gc.segment8,
gc.segment9,
gh.period_name
FROM gl_je_headers gh,
gl_je_lines gl,
gl_je_categories gjc,
gl_je_sources gjs,
gl_code_combinations gc,
gl_ledgers gl1
WHERE 1 = 1
AND gl1.ledger_id = gh.ledger_id
AND gh.je_header_id = gl.je_header_id
AND gjc.je_category_name = gh.je_category
AND gjs.je_source_name = gh.je_source
AND gl.code_combination_id = gc.code_combination_id
AND gl1.chart_of_accounts_id = gc.chart_of_accounts_id
-- AND gl1.currency_code!='USD'
AND gl1.NAME = 'Ledger1'
AND gh.period_name IN (SELECT period_name
FROM gl_periods a
WHERE 1 = 1
AND period_num BETWEEN 1 AND
(SELECT period_num
FROM gl_periods
WHERE period_name =
:p_accounting_period
AND
period_set_name =
a.period_set_name)
AND period_year IN
(SELECT period_year
FROM gl_periods
WHERE
period_name = :p_accounting_period
AND period_set_name =
a.period_set_name))
GROUP BY gjs.user_je_source_name,
gjc.user_je_category_name,
gl.currency_code,
gl.code_combination_id,
gh.period_name,
gc.segment1,
gc.segment2,
gc.segment3,
gc.segment4,
gc.segment5,
gc.segment6,
gc.segment7,
gc.segment8,
gc.segment9
```

Looking for your suggestions.

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us table and index definitions.

Comment: Oracle probably

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a READABLE query... Your one is a fine mess !

```
SELECT gjs.user_je_source_name "JOURNAL_SOURCE",
       gjc.user_je_category_name "JOURNAL_CATEGORY",
       gl.currency_code,
       0 AS reportingdebit,
       0 AS reportingcredit,
       Sum(COALESCE(gl.accounted_dr, 0)) AS ledgerdebit,
       Sum(COALESCE(gl.accounted_cr, 0)) AS ledgercredit,
       gl.code_combination_id,
       gc.segment1,
       gc.segment2,
       gc.segment3,
       gc.segment4,
       gc.segment5,
       gc.segment6,
       gc.segment7,
       gc.segment8,
       gc.segment9,
       gh.period_name
FROM   gl_je_headers gh
       JOIN gl_je_lines gl 
          ON gh.je_header_id = gl.je_header_id
       JOIN gl_je_categories gjc 
          ON gjc.je_category_name = gh.je_category
       JOIN gl_je_sources gjs 
          ON gjs.je_source_name = gh.je_source
       JOIN gl_code_combinations gc 
          ON gl.code_combination_id = gc.code_combination_id,
       JOIN gl_ledgers gl1 
          ON gl1.ledger_id = gh.ledger_id 
             AND gl1.chart_of_accounts_id = gc.chart_of_accounts_id
WHERE  gl1.NAME = 'Ledger1'
-- AND gl1.currency_code!='USD'
  AND  gh.period_name IN (SELECT period_name
                          FROM   gl_periods a
                          WHERE  period_num BETWEEN 1 AND (SELECT period_num
                                                           FROM   gl_periods
                                                           WHERE  period_name = :p_accounting_period
                                                           AND    period_set_name = a.period_set_name)
                            AND  period_year IN (SELECT period_year
                                                 FROM   gl_periods
                                                 WHERE  period_name = :p_accounting_period
                            AND period_set_name = a.period_set_name))
GROUP BY gjs.user_je_source_name,
         gjc.user_je_category_name,
         gl.currency_code,
         gl.code_combination_id,
         gh.period_name,
         gc.segment1,
         gc.segment2,
         gc.segment3,
         gc.segment4,
         gc.segment5,
         gc.segment6,
         gc.segment7,
         gc.segment8,
         gc.segment9
```

There is plenty of formatter on the web...

By the way NVL is Oracle old specific function to be replaced by COALESCE which is the ISO SQL standard
The same for JOIN.... and then **you will realize that the last one does a "triangular" join** :
Explaination :

Last join is
gl1 -- gh
gl1 -- gc (equivalent to gc -- gl1 because of equality)

But there is also :
gh -- gl
gl -- gc

The you have the circular reference :

gl1 -- gh ... gh -- gl ... gl -- gc ... gc -- gl1

That cannot be optimised. Probably :

- this is a join error
- your data model is incoherent